# How to get current app when user is in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-apps

I need to get from which admin page(app) current request is from in django admin.

Currently `request.resolver_match.app_name` only returns "admin" which is not what I want. 
I have noticed that my app name is in 'view_name' and 'url_name' but is it reliable to parse these variables to access current app name?
Django 1.11 LTS

EDIT: For example, when a user enters admin page for my course app with the above method I still only get 'admin' in my request which should be 'course' not 'admin'. My ultimate goal is to hide some of my app model fields in admin page based on user group.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a `ModelAdmin` you have access to the model via `self.model`. In a `ModelAdmin` method you can thus get the app name using `self.model._meta.app_label`.

I you need to access it from the template rather than the `ModelAdmin`, `self.model._meta` is passed to the context as `opts`. You can thus access it via `{% if opts.app_label == "some_app" %}`.

Comment: Thank you. using your answer I could access it through 'request.resolver_match.func.model_admin.model._meta.app_label' in mybaseAdmin class. Just one question, is it good practice to access it this way?

Comment: Yes. This API is documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/meta/

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this by tracking  `requested.user` i.e who is logged in currently.
something like this

```
if(requested.user=='admin'):
(show all fields)
else:
(show mentioned fields)
```

here you are restricting access of your's models fields based on `currently logged in user`

Comment: Can it be based on user group? I wrote an app to dynamically fetch accessible fields for each app in DjangoAdmin based on user group. I get user group by 'request.user.groups.name'. Now I need to find out which app admin page is requested to fetch allowed fields for that app admin.